# Angular - Argument of type '(error: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'

Tags: angular

I got this error handler code in Angular-11:

```ts
    return this.api.post('auth/user/login', data, headers).subscribe(
      (result: any) => {
        console.log(result.message);
        console.log(result.code);
        if (result.error === 'true' ){
          console.log(result.message);
        }
      },            
          data => this.tokenHandler(data),
          error => this.errorHandler(error.error)
     );
    }


    errorHandler(error: any){
      this.notify.clear();
    //  console.log(error);
      if (error.errors && error.errors.username){
        this.error = error.errors.username;
      }
      else if (error.message === 'Unauthorized'){
        this.error = null;
        this.notify.error('Invalid Login Details or email not confirmed', {timeout: 0})
      } else {
        this.error = null;
        this.notify.error(error.message, {timeout: 0})
      }
    }
```

But it resulted into these errors:

```js
Error: src / app / auth.component.ts: 84: 11 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type '(error: any) => void'
is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.

84 error => this.errorHandler(error.error) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules / rxjs / internal / Observable.d.ts: 54: 5
54 subscribe(next ? : (value: T) => void, error ? : (error: any) => void, complete ? : () => void): Subscription;
~~~~~~~~~
The last overload is declared here.


Error: src / app / auth.component.ts: 84: 11 - error TS7006: Parameter 'error'
implicitly has an 'any'
type.

84 error => this.errorHandler(error.error)
```

This line is highlighted: `error => this.errorHandler(error.error)`

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ - It was a mistake. It's Angular. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This explains it `subscribe(next ? : (value: T) => void, error ? : (error: any) => void, complete ? : () => void): Subscription;`

You're passing three arguments (callbacks) to `subscribe`, yes. However, your third callback, the error handler, doesn't match the third argument of the above function definition. It accepts a callback with no parameters as the third argument.

Instead, it looks like the first callback should get the token from the result (`result.data`?) and call `this.tokenHandler` there, and the second callback should be your error handler. Bacially getting rid of `data => this.tokenHandler(data),`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like `errorHandler` is getting called without an argument. Perhaps the error being passed to it has no `error` property? (Meaning `error.error` is undefined?)